# Custom WooCommerce Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I am writing a template and I've got all the partials in a `partials/` folder and I want to store the cart template at `partials/cart/cart.php` as apposed to `cart/cart.php` which is good but I do not know how I can now point woocommerce to that instead.

It's only a simple issue but I don't really know how the pages are called. Is there a way I can do this with changing hooks or something?

**Edit** Is there an easy way to over ride `woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-cart.php` from within my theme? At the end of the shortcode there I could just edit the path? Or it might just be easier to create my own shortcode

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with any hooks or anything I would suggest using a symlink the command might look something like this

`ln -s /var/www/wordpress_site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/partials/cart/cart.php /var/www/wordpress_site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`

Replace with your site location of course

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer: [How to modify WooCommerce cart, checkout pages (main theme portion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288722/how-to-modify-woocommerce-cart-checkout-pages-main-theme-portion) will help you

You can use function: wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) to get the ID of the page. This function will use the page setup as 'cart' page and not the slug. Meaning it will keep working also when you setup a different url for your 'cart' on the settings page. This works for all kind of Woocommerce special page, like 'checkout', 'shop' etc.

example:

```
if (wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) == get_the_ID()) {
 // Do something.
}
```